# Android: 9-patch image not stretching as expected

Tags: android, nine-patch

The actual image is this:

the red boxex are where i made 1 px black likes. Even the preview shows fine. So no problem with 9-patch

but the image i get for the following layout is:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_landing"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/loginheader"
    android:contentDescription="@string/login_header"
     />
```

[image]

I Expected, the logo to be on the left and black dots on the right and the rest of the space between them is filled with grey color i selected on the top

Thank You

Comment: Its already there in the question. Thats where i set the imageView background

Comment: Ive never known multiple lines to be used on the same side in a 9-patch. Have you tried it with just one. (I get that the preview is fine, but just to rule it out) http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/

Comment: yeah i even tried with only 1 mark on the left side. same result :(. Even with 2 marks, the preview is perfect. moreover i dont have any problem with the height. Regarding the width it is getting stretched but weirdly :(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Is your `ImageView` really bigger than your 9patch?
If not, you need to change `scaleType` as defaut is [FIT_CENTER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html).

Use `android:scaleType="fitXY"` or `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`.

Comment: My 9-patch Image is larger than the device screen in width. Thats why i get such a result??? I read: 9-patch images must be as small as possible because they can be stretched but cannot be shrinked. So, either i have to make the Image too small and then 9-patch it or set attributes as you suggested???

Comment: adjustViewBounds did it

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your 9 patch is larger than the ImageView that you are trying to put it in.  Try setting the ImageView to wrap_content to see if it fixes the problem. If it does, try making the 9 patch smaller, the ImageView bigger or set the scaleType as pcans mentioned.

Comment: My 9-patch Image is larger than the device screen in width. Thats why i get such a result??? I read: 9-patch images must be as small as possible because they can be stretched but cannot be shrinked. So, either i have to make the Image too small and then 9-patch it or set attributes as pcans suggested???